# как работать с вещественными числами MIPS?

Tags: ассемблер, mips

В MIPS есть специальные команды и регистры для работы с вещественными числами. 
Например, вот такая команда работает с целыми числами:

```
add $s0, $s0, $s1
```

Она записывает в регистр $s0 сумму $s0 и $s1. Для работы с вещественными нужно написать так:

```
add.d $f0, $f0, $f1
```

Регистры, начинающиеся с f - это как раз регистры для вещественных чисел. Если в последней команде указать регистры, начинающиеся не с f - то есть обычные регистры - то будет ошибка компиляции.

Для целых чисел есть еще такая команда:

```
addi $s0, $s0, 10
```

Она записывает в $s0 сумму $s0 и 10. То есть вначале, когда во всех регистрах ноль ее можно использовать что бы записать в регистры какие то значения, а уже потом с ними работать. Но нет аналога этой команды для вещественных чисел. Получается странная ситуация есть команды и регистры для вещественных чисел, но в этих регистрах всегда ноль. Подскажите пожалуйста, как записать в них значения?

Comment: [Нужен перевод](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2589233/2076787).

Answer (score 1):

В MIPS для этого есть инструкции `li.s` и `l.d`. Первая инициализирует регистр непосредственным операндом; вторая берет значение из памяти. Например:

```
.data
    val: .double 1.0
.text
    li.s $f1, 1.0
    l.d  $f2, val
```